# How can i call a window child function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, frames

I am calling the parent function like `window.parent.functionname();` from the child page. How can i call the `window.child.function()` from the parent page to child page.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am guessing you are talking about calling a function within an iFrame within the current document. If so please add that to your question.

Comment: No i am not having any iframe

Comment: if you're using `window.parent` and it's working, then you have an iframe.

Comment: It will be in the tabstrip. I am using dhtmlx tabstrip to load the child pages. some code: `tabbar.setHrefMode("iframes-on-demand");
             tabbar.setContentHref("a1", "../../MailContactMain/Index");` Then can i call using a1 id

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Give your iFrame an id and try

```
document.getElementById("iFrameId").contentWindow.functionname()
```

This works even when you have multiple iFrames in the same page irrespective of their order.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have an iframe?

Do something like that:

```
window.frames[0].contentDocument.functionname();
```

Comment: I am not having any frames. Then how can i do that

Comment: @Naidu And where or what is your child? When you make window.parent in which context are you? Give me more code?!

Comment: I am using dhtmlx tabbar to display the child. code:`tabbar.setHrefMode("iframes-on-demand");
             tabbar.setContentHref("a1", "../../MailContactMain/Index");` then will i use a1 as iframe

Comment: Oh, I never used that before. But there has to be an iframe or frame. Without a frame the property window.parent is the same link just  window (window.parent == window) => true

Comment: If you are in a frame, then window.parent is the frame-holder-document. If you are in the frame-holder-document, then use window.frames[0] OR window.frames[1] to switch in the frame-context. Look here: http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/frames.htm

Answer (score 3):

**Parent page**

```
var windowRef = null;

function openChildWindow() {
    if ((windowRef != null) && (windowRef.closed == false)) {
        if (windowRef.closed == false) windowRef.close();
        windowRef = null;
    }

    var windowUrl = 'ChildPage.aspx';
    var windowId = 'NewWindow_' + new Date().getTime();
    var windowFeatures = 'channelmode=no,directories=no,fullscreen=no,' + 'location=no,dependent=yes,menubar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,' + 'status=no,toolbar=no,titlebar=no,' + 'left=0,top=0,width=400px,height=200px';

    windowRef = window.open(windowUrl, windowId, windowFeatures);

    windowRef.focus();

    // Need to call on a delay to allow
    // the child window to fully load...
    window.setTimeout(callChildWindowFunction(), 1000);
}

function callChildWindowFunction() {
    if ((windowRef != null) && (windowRef.closed == false)) windowRef.childWindowFunction();
}​
```

**Child Page**

```
function childWindowFunction() {
    alert('Hello from childWindowFunction()');
}​
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var win = null;
function openAndCall(id){
    if (win!=null && win.closed==false){
        win.close();
    }
    win = window.open("/somePage");
    win.onload = function(){
        win.callSome(id);
    };
}
```